# Can I recover multiple images from GStreamer if I sink multiple buffers to one image?

Tags: ubuntu, gstreamer

I'm interested in capturing two images simultaneously from my USB 3.0 webcam with gstreamer on Ubuntu 18.04. With this pipeline, I've noticed if I increment num-buffers to 2, I get double the file size with the single image.

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video3 num-buffers=1 ! image/jpeg,width=4208,height=3120 ! filesink location=/root/test3.jpg
```

Is there a way to split the file back into two separate images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `multifilesink` instead of `filesink` in this case.

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video3 num-buffers=2 ! image/jpeg,width=4208,height=3120 ! multifilesink location=/root/test_%05d.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you Florian - GST is new to me and I'm having trouble finding the right documentation. Cheers.